# How to prevent a contenteditable div from rendering html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/tb8ryyp6/1/

As you can see if we drag and drop image to contenteditable `div` its content is rendered as HTML. I want to prevent this behavior. Currently I solved this problem with attaching event handler to contenteditable `div` on drop event like this `ondrop='return false;'`.

**This works for me.**

```
<div contenteditable='true' ondrop='return false;'>
```

**But**. This solution seems not to be a cross-browser solution and user can remove this even handler easily at any time by changing HTML source code in dev-tools.

In general I want to prevent a contenteditable `div` from rendering any HTML element. This element could be not just image it could be an anchor element for example. As solution it can be both a cross-browser preventing of drop actions or showing HTML as text. But first one is preferable.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The user can change ANYTHING on your page ! What do you want to do ? prevent the drop or add the image as text ?

Comment: in general i want to prevent a contenteditable div from rendering any html element. this element could be not just image it could be an anchor element for example. As solution it can be both a cross-browser disabling of drop actions or showing html as text. But first one is preferable.

Comment: Use a `textarea` then !

Comment: contenteditable div fits better for my markup and design.

Comment: @Emil https://jsfiddle.net/0hhdpsvx/

Comment: What do you expect ?

Comment: A content editable div which renders no HTML is essentially just a textarea, so I suggest you use that instead.

Comment: >But... this solution seems not to be a cross-browser solution and user can remove this even handler easily at any time by changing html source code in dev-tools.< Cross-browser? Please be specific as to which browsers behave and how you expect these rogue browsers to behave. As for dev-tools, changing stuff on your page is the tool's purpose, it's not permanent, and no one else but that user would see the changes. If you're worried about the layout differences between a div and a textarea, then wrap a div around a textarea, problem solved.

Comment: I thank you all for a `textarea`proposal but `textarea`doesnt fit to my site as good as a contenteditable div.

Comment: "*prevent a contenteditable div from rendering html*" Back in *my* days, these are called `<textarea>`!

Comment: Anyone can remove the events, heck they can submit whatever to your server without even touching your code. Clientside is the wrong place to worry about security. Clean up the code on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you can design a `<textarea>` just like anything else. But what you want can also be done with a `<div contenteditable>`.

> user can remove this even handler at any time by changing html source code in dev-tools.

If you use `addEventListener("drop", func)`, the event listener isn't visible in the html code. It can still be removed though, but then it's not your problem if the website doesn't work properly anymore (it's only changed in the browser, not on the server!)

This code uses the `innerText` property (which contains the unformatted text). Since line breaks are `\n` in `innerText` and `<br>` in the `<div>`, it has to be converted.

```js
var ediv = document.getElementById("ediv");

function noHTML() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var str1 = ediv.innerText.replace(/\n/g,"");
        var str2 = ediv.innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g,"");
        
        if (str1 != str2) {
            ediv.innerText = ediv.innerText;
        }
    }, 1);
}

// Remove markup when dropping something (e.g. image/ link)
ediv.addEventListener("drop", noHTML);
// Remove markup when pasting something (e.g. from Microsoft Word)
ediv.addEventListener("paste", noHTML);
// Remove markup from the clipboard when copying something
ediv.addEventListener("copy", function(e) {
    noHTML();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        var text = window.getSelection().toString();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.clipboardData.setData('Text', text);
    }
});
// Remove markup when the div gains focus
ediv.addEventListener("focus", noHTML);
// Remove markup when the div loses focus
ediv.addEventListener("blur", noHTML);
```

```css
#ediv{
  background-color: white;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px dotted blue; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
[placeholder]:empty:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #ddd; 
}
[placeholder]:empty:focus:before {
    content: "";
}
#img {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='ediv' contenteditable='true' placeholder='i am contenteditable div..'></div>

<div id='img'>
  <span>drag and drop this image to contenteditable div</span>
  <br>
  <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_March_2010-1.jpg' width='220px'><br>
  <a href='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_March_2010-1.jpg'>Hyperlink</a>
</div>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tb8ryyp6/3/)**